# Angular: Get the index of the dropdown item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following in my view

```
<div>
    <select ng-model="obj.arr[otherObj.variable]" ng-change="otherObj.variable=SOMETHING">
        <option ng-repeat="label in obj.arrs">{{label}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Without the `ng-change` attribute, this code does what I want when `otherObj.variable` is one of the indexes of the obj.arr - it selects the correct item in the list.

What I want in addition to this is to set `otherObj.variable` to the index of the array item that is picked when the dropdown variable is changed.  So, if the second value in the dropdown is picked then `otherObj.variable` should be set to 1.  I tried to do this with a

```
ng-change="otherObj.variable=SOMETHING"
```

Problem is., I don't know what that `SOMETHING` should be.  Am I doing this right?

**EDIT**

My requirements are

1. Select the top option in the dropdown by default
2. select the appropriate item in the array depending on the value of otherObj.variable (this gets set by some external code so if I come to the page with this value set then I want the correct option selected)
3. Make sure otherObj.variable is updated if I change the value in the dropdown.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle link

Comment: Not really.  You have the selected value in the model associated with the select.  Use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of ngRepeat to generate the values automatically on the option elements.

Comment: Are you really sure you want this? What you are doing is essentially `obj.arr[otherObj.variable] = obj.arrs[selected index]`.

Comment: @zeroflagL These are the requirements 1. select the top option in the dropdown by default  2.  select the appropriate item in the array depending on the value of otherObj.variable (this gets set by some external code so if I come to the page with this value set then I want the  correct option selected) 3. Make sure otherObj.variable is updated if I change the value in the dropdown.

Comment: Using indexes is stupid - this usually means that if you place 'label in obj.arrs | cleverFilter' it will break your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
angular.module('selects.demo', [])
.controller('SelectCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.values = [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'aLabel',
  }, {
    id: 2,
    label: 'bLabel',
  }];
  
  $scope.selectedval = $scope.values[0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selects.demo">
  <div ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
    <p>Using ngOptions without select as:</p>
    <select ng-model="selectedval" ng-options="value.label for value in values"></select>
    <p>{{selectedval}}</p>
    
    <p>Using ngOptions with select as statement: (this will return just the id in the model)</p>
    <select ng-model="selectedval2" ng-options="value.id as value.label for value in values"></select>
    <p>{{selectedval2}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if my comment was a little cryptic.  [Select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) elements like other form elements are actually directives in AngularJS, so they do a lot of stuff for you automatically.  You **don't need to use an ngChang**e to populate the ngModel associated with your select element.  AngularJS will handle that for you.

Also, you can use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of ngRepeat on select elements to generate the values automatically on options.

Assuming that you have an object with values:

```
$scope.values = [{
  id: 1,
  label: 'aLabel',
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'bLabel',
}];
```

You would write:

```
<select ng-model="selectedval" ng-options="value.label for value in values"></select>
```

Now your ngModel is going to be bound to the selected element.  It will be set with the value of the object that was chosen.  If you add `{{selectedval.id}}` to your view, it will display the id of the selected element.

If you want to set the value to the first item, in your controller, you would add:

```
$scope.selectedval = $scope.values[0];
```

If you want to update some property on $scope.values based on the selected value, you could use something like:

```
$scope.addActiveProp = function() {
  var selected = $scope.values.filter(function(e) { return e == $scope.selectedval; });
  selected.active = true;
}
```

And then run the addActiveProp fn in ngChange on the select.

Comment: What would I write then?

Comment: Updated.  Does that help?

Comment: P.S. I just read your updated comment.  If you want to set the value to the first option, you can do that by: `$scope.selectedval = $scope.values[0];` in your controller

Comment: So, should selectedValue be the integer id or the object consisting of the id and label?

Comment: Thanks! Always nice to hear that.

Comment: It could be either depending on how you set up ngOptions.   Using select as will bind the result of the select expression to the model, but the value of the <select> and <option> html elements will be either the index (for array data sources) or property name (for object data sources) of the value within the collection.

Comment: I added a little demo so you can see the difference between using ngOptions with and without a select as.

Answer (score 1):

Please give a try with below code

```
<select ng-model="obj.arr[otherObj.variable]" ng-change="otherObj.variable=key" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in obj.arrs"></select>
```

Comment: Yes.  Plus 1 for effort